# Can I change username?

Tags: support

Can I change the username I have all over StackExchange without re-registering?

It seems like my question wasn't long enough...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum faucibus orci non tellus consectetur sit amet viverra sapien pellentesque. Duis et massa in dui pellentesque dapibus eu vitae sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam molestie, neque vel porta pulvinar, elit elit placerat risus, a molestie quam est vitae leo. Praesent gravida metus ut sem rhoncus vitae vestibulum tellus laoreet. Proin bibendum, erat ut suscipit convallis, diam enim dictum neque, et tempor velit felis egestas elit. Aliquam id tempor lectus. Vestibulum rutrum cursus sapien vitae malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque risus non mi sodales feugiat. Aenean aliquam, neque eu luctus mollis, odio arcu pretium velit, pharetra cursus mi justo vel urna. In adipiscing erat rhoncus tellus pharetra vehicula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, you can, using the "edit" link on your profile page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25740/is-it-possible-to-change-your-username) I am not sure if this change affects your account on all StackExchange sites or if you have to do them individually.

Comment: Thanks! You know, I already tried doing what you said, but I couldn't find the Edit-button. Then I realized that there was no Edit-button on the meta.avp.stackexchange.com or at stackexchange.com. You have to do it on a "regular" SE page.